# Have you had DLL's fail after upgrading to 64 bit server?

Tags: asp-classic, 64-bit

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced failed DLL's after upgrading their servers.

My company is in the process of upgrading our code and server's after ten years of using classic ASP. We've set up our new server running Windows 2008 and IIS 7. Our classic ASP code and our new asp.net mvc code work pretty well.

Our problems started happening when we began moving our old websites to the new server. When trying to load the page on the actual server machine's browser, we initially got a 500 error. If we refreshed the page then some of the page would load but then display an error:

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> /folder/scriptname.asp, line 24
>
> 800401f3

*btw: On remote machines we would just get 500 errors.*

Line 24 is the first executable code in the script:

```
'23 lines of comments

set A0SQL_DATA = server.createobject("olddllname.Data")

'the rest of the script
```

That specific line is trying to use a ten year old DLL to create a server object. I don't think the server configuration is a problem because I'm able to create "adodb.recordset" server objects without any problems.

Is there an issue when running correctly registered old DLL's on 64 bit systems?

Is there a way to get old DLL's working on 64 bit systems?

### Edit

I have confirmed that the site's application pool is running in 32bit compatability mode, but the site still sends the same errors whenever `set A0SQL_DATA = server.createobject("olddllname.Data")` is called.

Comment: When you say upgrade - is that from 2k3 64 bit to 2k8 R2 (64 bit) or ...  is the dll 64 bit?

Comment: If you've changed operating systems entirely such as Greg is asking about, then another culprit could be permissions.  Windows has gradually tightened permissions from edition to edition, and your DLL may be trying to do something that it doesn't have permission to do in the context of the account it is running under.  It may have worked fine on older editions of Windows where permissions were less granular and less restrictive by default.

Comment: @Greg - I'm not sure exactly what your question means. I know we were on a 32bit operating system before, now we're on windows server 2008.

Comment: @quakkels, does your olddllname.Data rely on anything else? It looks like your progid is not registered in this 64bit machine. Do you need to register (regsvr32) the DLL or its dependencies? Try running a simple standalone application that calls your "CreateObject". Good luck

Comment: @Syd - I did create a simple classic asp app that uses CreateObject to create an adodb.recordset object. That was successfull

Comment: @AaronSL - regarding permissions, My sys admin assures me that all the accounts on this server have admin permissions. He did that to specifically rule out permissions being the issue.

Comment: @quakkels - you did not answer my question. my question is that can you CreateObject ("olddllname.Data") in a standalone application? can you also confirm olddllname.Data is registered (check your registry)?

Comment: I'll check when i get back to work

Comment: @Syd - I'm not sure what this means. I create a new .asp page and tried to create an object using the olddllname.Data and I got the same error. The guy who wrote the dll is so far refusing to show his source or help us troubleshoot. I'm frusterated.

Comment: hi quakkels, let's get back to basics. get the deployment instructions from the vendor (he would definitely obliged as he is a professional). then follow his deployment instructions (which include doing the necessary registration). that would be a start

Comment: @Syd - There isn't really a vendor because this particular dll was developed in-house. I don't want to go too far into it but there are office politics that seem to be trying to sabatoge the upgrade. My sys admin and I are going to retrace our steps (go back to basics as you said) and see if we missed anything. Thanks for everybody's ongoing help! If we do find the solution I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an issue when running correctly registered old DLL's on 64 bit systems?

Yes, the most prominent example of a 32-bit DLL no longer working on 64-bit Windows seems to be the Microsoft Jet Engine, i.e., the driver required to access .mdb files. Since [there is no 64-bit version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957570), the only way to access .mdb files in classic ASP application is to run IIS (or the Application Pool, to be precise) in 32-bit compatibility mode.

---

How to detect if you are in 32 or 64 bit mode (untested):

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Response.Write shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%")
```

This should output `AMD64` in 64-bit mode and `x86` in 32-bit mode (either native 32-bit or 32-bit emulation on a 64-bit processor).

Comment: I talked to my sys admin... he believes that the site is already in 32bit mode. Is there a way I can confirm that? could there be a different problem?

Comment: @quakkels: I've added some ASP code to test if you are in 32 or 64-bit mode.

Comment: @Heinzi - Thanks for the code. It shows "x86" but the site still does not run this dll

Comment: @quakkels: Then there must be some other issue. Is the DLL registered correctly? Since it's a 32-bit COM object, you might want to try `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\regsvr32 path\to\your\old\dll.dll`

Comment: @Heinzi - My admin doublechecked that all the dlls were registered. Still no change in the error text.

Comment: Do you have Office installed on your server? If yes, try to run `set A0SQL_DATA = CreateObject("olddllname.Data")` in the Immediate Window of a VBA project. If that fails, you know that your error has nothing to do with IIS.

Comment: @Heinzi - We just got word 2007 installed on the server and I ran your line of code in a macro `set A0SQL_DATA = CreateObject("olddllname.Data")`. The macro errored and delivered `Compile Error: Invalid outside procedure.` I'm not sure what this tells us other than it doesn't work regardless of IIS 7.5. Could it be that the dll is 16bit?

Comment: @quakkels: Ah, that's just a VBA error. Run it in the Immediate Window (you get there with `Ctrl-g`).

Answer (score 1):

Well, error 800401f3 means "invalid class name."  That strongly suggests that the DLL is registered with the wrong ProgId (or that the ProgId is missing entirely).  When your sys admin verified that the DLL was registered, did he also verify that its ProgId is "olddllname.Data"?

Comment: Hmmm... I'll double check with him.